# tab bar controller can not display view controllers

Tags: ios, tabbarcontroller

Here my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    CSDisplayPlaza *displayPlaza = [[CSDisplayPlaza alloc] initWithNibName:@"CSDisplayPlaza" bundle:nil];
    [displayPlaza setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"one" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"displayPlaza"] tag:0]];
    UINavigationController *displayPlazaNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:displayPlaza];

    CSGameHall *gameHall = [[CSGameHall alloc] initWithNibName:@"CSGameHall" bundle:nil];
    [gameHall setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"two" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"displayPlaza"] tag:1]];
    UINavigationController *gameHallNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:gameHall];

    CSMyInformation *myInformation = [[CSMyInformation alloc] initWithNibName:@"CSMyInformation" bundle:nil];
    [myInformation setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"three" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myInformation"] tag:2]];
    UINavigationController *myInformationNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myInformation];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:displayPlazaNav,gameHallNav,myInformationNav,nil]];
    [tabBarController setSelectedViewController:displayPlazaNav];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In the simulator, cannot display any view controllers. Just a empty tabbar in my simulator. I don't know what happen.

Comment: When you say empty, do you mean you get no title or image in the tab bar? Do you have things in your displayPlaza and gameHall views to see?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is displayPlaza is nil for some reason. Add log messages after you create every object to verify you in fact created one, and also the tab bar controllers array.